# Mass file renaming from from text file

Tags: linux, rename

I have a folder with about 7,000 files and each file is numbered e.g. 74857.mkv 74858.mkv etc.

[image]

I also have a text file which has all the file numbers and file names:

In this order:

[image]

I would like to rename each file from its number to its name; an example:

74857.mkv > Taken S01 E01.mkv

74858.mkv > Taken S01 E02.mkv

Any commands to do this please I have been doing it manually and only managed to do 50 files in 5 days!

Comment: Is *"it's name example"* the name on the line immediately above? it's not clear from your example (your numbers aren't consistent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do these in small batches and test with a copy if I were you but something like this should do you

```
while read n; do read f; mv $f "$n.${f##*.}"; done < file
```

Before you start you would be well advised to check the output of

```
while read n; do read f; echo mv $f "$n.${f##*.}"; done < file > checkfile
```

To make sure there are no errors in your renaming file.

Safer if you have the space and the time to copy to keep your originals safe until you are happy....

```
while read n; do read f; cp $f "/a/safe/location/$n.${f##*.}"; done < file
```

**Note**

To reverse the process you just need to reverse the order of the names in the `mv` command

```
mv "$n.${f##*.}"  $f
```

Comment: Hi,Where do I write the text files name that has the list of names of each file? while read n; do read f; echo mv $f "$n.${f##*.}"; done < file > checkfile

Comment: Thats the `< file` part. Change it to `< myfiles.txt` or whatever. If you haven't done this before, run a test using it in anger..... check all output with the `echo` version first and run with the 'cp' version if you have space. Slower but far far safer if you are unfamiliar with scripts.

Comment: Hi Mate, I can't thank you so much for your help and support I tried your script and the checkfile.txt is showing as them like this: https://prnt.sc/q1xztn Its made a third line with the .mkv extensions I have not tried with the files as some files are mp4 and avi so if it removes the extensions than It will be hard for me to know which extension the file is.

Comment: Did you check your txt file for blank lines? Is it a Windows text file (run it through `dos2unix` if it is). Either of those may be part of your problem. Also I tested @steeldriver solution and it works like a charm but both solutions rely on the txt file being correct.

Comment: You my friend are a genius! You are the man! Yes it was edited in windows sorry I learnt something new.. I used this one because some of my files in different extensions ie .mp4 .avi but you done it all my files are names perfect!

Comment: Can I bother you for the last time, how can I reverse this action ie find all names and change them back to the original numbering based on the  original text file and numbering? I tried reversing the commands but didn't work.. Just curious that's all I am soo happy to have renamed 8000 files in under a second!

Comment: No bother. TBH if you are new to `Linux` then jumping in with a rename of 8k files with all the potential for disaster was a brave move. Glad it went well. Welcome to the site. Stick around.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that *"it's name example"* is the string on the line immediately above the current `.mkv` file name i.e. that given

```
$ cat file.txt 
Taken S01 E01
74857.mkv
Taken S01 E02
74858.mkv
```

you actually want

> **74857**.mkv > Taken S01 E01.mkv
>
> **74858**.mkv > Taken S01 E02.mkv

then with GNU `parallel` and `mv`:

```
parallel -N2 echo mv -- {2} {1}.mkv < file.txt
```

Remove the `echo` once you are happy that it is composing the correct commands.

Comment: Doesn't this omit the suffix? `{1}.mkv`? assuming all are mkv files

Comment: @bu5hman oops thanks - should be better now

Comment: @bu5hman AFAIK GNU `parallel` (unlike `xargs` for example) delimits on newlines by default; it seems to have no problem with the whitespace when I test it on my system

Comment: Just seen that when I tested. lesson learned Like the use of `parallel` though. If I were doing this I think that `mv {2} {1}.{2}` would be a good move in either my or your code as it allows OP to revert back to the original naming very easily even if there is a problem in the name list file.

Comment: @steeldriver Use `--dry-run` instead of `echo`. That way you can review more complex commands (e.g. composed commands or redirection to files).

Comment: Hi, This is the example of echo I get https://prnt.sc/q1y67c and also some of my files end in .mp4 and .avi.. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @alexisakakios based on your screenshot, your text file containing the mappings likely has Windows (CRLF) line endings. Please add the information about the file suffixes to your question.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lne '$dst = "$_.mkv"; $src = <>; chomp $src; rename $src, $dst
  or warn "$src -> $dst: $!\n"' your-file
```

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/files # to get a builtin mv
while IFS= read -ru3 dst && IFS= read -ru3 src; do
   mv -- "$src" "$dst.mkv"
done 3< your-file
```